# "What is the probability both houses will be completed after 7 weeks?" meaning

Tags: meaning, prepositions, time, mathematics

When the question asks if the houses will be completed "after 7 weeks", 
someone says; it isn't asking if it will take greater than 7 weeks to complete the houses. "After 7 weeks" means "as soon as seven weeks have passed." or at the end of day 49.

How about if I want to say 'it takes greater than 7 weeks', what is the proper sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way to ask would be

> What is the probability that neither house is completed after seven weeks.

I'm not very clear, but the sentence can be used to ask about greater than 7 weeks.

If the probability that both houses are completed after seven weeks is 25%, then the probability that at least one house will take greater than 7 weeks to complete is 75%.

In the context, I assume that the houses will *eventually* be finished. If this assumption is not correct you need to be explicit:

> What is the probability that both houses will be completed, but it will take longer than seven weeks.
>
> What is the probability that one (or both) of the houses will never be completed, even after seven weeks?

Or more casually:

> Are you ever going to finish building my house!?